# SQL Server Integration Services Package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have just recently started using SSIS and it's been a great ride so far. I get an error message when attempting to add an existing package. My guess is that packages that were created on an original computer cannot be globally accessed even if you have the .dtsx file?

Below, is a link of the image of the error I am getting.

http://imgur.com/B95pVg5

Please give me any help!

Comment: Could you include the text of the error message in your question please?

Comment: Was the package you're trying to add created in the same version of SSIS?